# Проверьте, пожалуйста: придаточное уступки?

Tags: синтаксис

*Ей было лет двадцать, не больше, и она не была настроена на карнавал, **если, конечно, нарочито не вырядилась убогой.***

Спасибо!

Comment: Придаточные уступки требуют других союзов. Здесь, например:  http://bitclass.ru/rus/theory/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: bah что-то у меня с уступками как-то нехорошо получается : ( сеичас буду внимательно разбираться! спасибо за линк!!! : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...она не была настроена на карнавал, если, конечно, нарочито не вырядилась убогой.

**Это семантический подтип СПП с придаточным условия со значением логического обоснования**: в придаточной части содержится основание, а в главной - вывод, умозаключение.

**Похожие предложения**:

Если он не уезжает, значит, ему там нравится. Вероятно, игра актера была блистательна, если на следующий день в кассу выстроилась огромная очередь.

Comment: А частица "не" никакой роли не играет для классификации придаточного?  "Она" могла и быть настроена, но всё-таки, невзирая на своё настроение, "вырядилась убогой"...

Comment: Я определяю грамматическую структуру предложения, а вот смысл без контекста не очень ясен. Мне кажется, что здесь говорится о бедно одетой девушке, пришедшей на праздник. Это ИРОНИЯ, автор говорит, что, может быть,  это она "нарядилась" убогой.

Comment: УТВЕРЖДЕНИЕ "она не была настроена на карнавал" верно при  УСЛОВИИ исключения варианта с " нарядом под  убогую". Обычная математическая формула:  верно а, если соблюдается b. Поэтому СОПОСТАВЛЕНИЕ ЗДЕСЬ ОТСУТСТВУЕТ, а грамматика определяется вариативно: или однородные сказуемые, или неполное предложение в составе сложного.

Comment: "верно а, если соблюдается b" не проходит, тогда уж "верно а, если  НЕ СОБЛЮДАЕТСЯ b", а это уже  сопоставление, от условия лишь оттенок " А , но возможно и b"   : девушка   не была настроена на карнавал, но возможно, нарочито вырядилась убогой. Видимо, наряд был далеко не праздничный.

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, это придаточное сопоставительное с союзом если не ...и пропуском его продолжения ...то...

В пользу этого утверждения говорит тот факт, что по содержанию предложения равноправны, как в сложносочинённом, что характерно для сопоставления. Смысл:она не была настроена на карнавал или нарочито  вырядилась убогой.
Сопоставляются условия восприятия факта неподготовленности к карнавалу.

Во 2 предложении нет условия, при котором бы совершилось действие Нельзя сказать:...она не была настроена на карнавал (при каком условии?), если, конечно, нарочито не вырядилась убогой.